# How to remove div's slight white edge?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations, mozilla

Below is a part of my code. Problem is how to remove tiny white line on the blue rounded box in **mozilla firefox 50.1.0**

[image]

```css
.s{
  animation: 2s ease-out 0s normal none infinite running r0;
  background: #639dcf none repeat scroll 0 0; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 200px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes r0 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 0px #639dcf;
  }
  10% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #4f90c9, 0 0 12px 14px #4f90c9;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 40px #639dcf;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes r0 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 0px #639dcf;
  }
  10% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #4f90c9, 0 0 12px 14px #4f90c9;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 40px #639dcf;
  }
}
@keyframes r0 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 0px #639dcf;
  }
  10% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #4f90c9, 0 0 12px 14px #4f90c9;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 40px #639dcf;
  }
}
```

```html
<div type="button" id="menuOrb" class="s m1 "></div>
```

Comment: ....where is the border?

Comment: There is nothing "white" in the code.

Comment: I didn't code for border, but still you can see a tiny white line on blue round box (like Illusion). you can in snippet

Comment: Not an answer but I hope you know that `box-shadow` animations are very intensive and should be avoided as much as possible from a performance perspective.

Comment: I don't think there is any border. It's just our eyes, that see it that way because your inner circle is Solid and outer animation is made up of `box-shadow` thus when that `box-shadow` animation starts from Solid border's edges, it appears as a white border. As the color level of `box-shadow`'s **spread** and your **solid circle** do not match. Try running the animation with slower duration.

Comment: @Maddy: I don't see what you have indicated in the screenshot. Browser details? I am on an older version of Chrome (v47).

Comment: Its mozilla firefox 50.1.0 @Harry

Comment: Ah, I don't have FF on my office PC and so can't check that now. Anyway, try adding that info also to the question. It may help. I can see what's happening, there will always be a little space between the element's background (which is inside its border) and its box-shadow (which is outside its border) but I can't work on a fix because in my browser I don't see it at all. Try setting `background-origin: border-box`, `background-clip: border-box` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is actually due to a color mismatch in the keyframes. At `0%` and `100%` you're using color code `#639dcf` where at `10%` you're using `#4f90c9`. This is causing enough of a difference between the `box-shadow` and the `background-color` of your circle for there to appear to be a "white" gap.

Try changing your keyframes to use:

```
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 0px #639dcf;
  }
  10% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 12px 14px #639dcf;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 40px #639dcf;
  }
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5o5375ja/)**

---

**FIREFOX UPDATE**

Having tested in OSX Firefox v50.1.0, you are correct, there is a trail of antialiasing pixels that surrounds the circle as a result of `border-radius`. To combat this, the best solution I have found is to leverage the pseudo element `:after` and "cover" the offending trail with its own border.

**CSS**

```
.s{
  animation: 2s ease-out 0s normal none infinite running r0;
  background: #639dcf none repeat scroll 0 0;   
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 200px;
  position:relative;
}
.s:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-2px;
  left:-2px;
  bottom:-2px;
  right:-2px;
  border:3px solid #639dcf;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5o5375ja/2/)**

Before vs. after
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but did you check this in `firefox`

Comment: @Maddy, updated, apologise for the assumption about the color, have restored the previous color in my update and found a workaround

Comment: Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Give your `.s` a border of same color as background.

```css
.s{
  animation: 2s ease-out 0s normal none infinite running r0;
  background: #639dcf none repeat scroll 0 0; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:1px solid #639dcf;
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  width: 90px;
  margin:100px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes r0 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 0px #639dcf;
  }
  10% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #4f90c9, 0 0 12px 14px #4f90c9;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 40px #639dcf;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes r0 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 0px #639dcf;
  }
  10% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #4f90c9, 0 0 12px 14px #4f90c9;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 40px #639dcf;
  }
}
@keyframes r0 {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 0px #639dcf;
  }
  10% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #4f90c9, 0 0 12px 14px #4f90c9;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px #639dcf, 0 0 0px 40px #639dcf;
  }
}
```

```html
<div type="button" id="menuOrb" class="s m1 "></div>
```